# Singularity 3.6.2 Installation

Tags: go, installation, singularity-container

I have problems with installation of singularity 3.6.2 in linux mint, I followed the instructions of https://sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/installation.html.
I installed the dependencies and Go.

Then I run the command for install the latest version:

```
export VERSION=3.6.2 && # adjust this as necessary \
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/sylabs && \
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/sylabs && \
wget https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/releases/download/v${VERSION}/singularity-${VERSION}.tar.gz && \
tar -xzf singularity-${VERSION}.tar.gz && \
cd ./singularity && \
./mconfig
```

The error is:

```
    Configuring for project `singularity' with languages: C, Golang
=> running pre-basechecks project specific checks ...
=> running base system checks ...
 checking: host C compiler... cc
 checking: host C++ compiler... c++
 checking: host Go compiler (at least version 1.13)... not found!
mconfig: could not complete configuration
```

I have go (go version)

```
go version go1.15.2 linux/amd64
```

I don't know what happend!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with the same error. All the suggestions say that probably you have an older version of Go and that's why. But turned out it's even more important to place Go and Singularity in the right locations.

I found these docs https://github.com/hpcng/singularity/blob/release-3.5/INSTALL.md are the most useful and correct about where to put what in terms of directories.

The key is to clone Singularity in a directory which is GOPATH:

You won't have this directory by default so create it first

```
$ mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/sylabs && \
  cd ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/sylabs && \
  git clone https://github.com/sylabs/singularity.git && \
  cd singularity
```

Make sure your singularity is here: **{GOPATH}/src/github.com/sylabs/singularity**

**To summarize:**

The Go itself is located here `/usr/local/go`

GOPATH would be something like `home/your_username/go` and the singularity will be located inside in e.g. `home/your_username/go/src/github.com/sylabs/singularity`

Comment: the link you attached goes to 404 :(

Answer (score 4):

If someone faces this issue, follow this installation [guide](https://github.com/hpcng/singularity/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

```
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential \
libseccomp-dev pkg-config squashfs-tools cryptsetup

sudo rm -r /usr/local/go

export VERSION=1.13.15 OS=linux ARCH=amd64  # change this as you need

wget -O /tmp/go${VERSION}.${OS}-${ARCH}.tar.gz https://dl.google.com/go/go${VERSION}.${OS}-${ARCH}.tar.gz && \
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf /tmp/go${VERSION}.${OS}-${ARCH}.tar.gz

echo 'export GOPATH=${HOME}/go' >> ~/.bashrc && \
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin' >> ~/.bashrc && \
source ~/.bashrc

curl -sfL https://install.goreleaser.com/github.com/golangci/golangci-lint.sh |
sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.21.0

mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/sylabs && \
cd ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/sylabs && \
git clone https://github.com/sylabs/singularity.git && \
cd singularity

git checkout v3.6.3

cd ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/sylabs/singularity && \
./mconfig && \
cd ./builddir && \
make && \
sudo make install

singularity version
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was reported in [5099](https://github.com/hpcng/singularity/issues/5099).

[# 5320](https://github.com/hpcng/singularity/issues/5320) also mentions:

> I deleted the PPO python 3.6 and this worked fine!

Make sure nothing is executed as root, which would have a $PATH different from your current user.

Answer (score -1):

Rookie here, but I figured it out (in my own way). Open your terminal, type: go env, check the GOPROXY=?, in my case: GOPATH=/home/{$my_username}/go. There is no direactory named go (/home/{$my_username}/go doesn't exist), I don't know why GO set up that PATH in env automatically as it's installed.

I tried to use "go env -w GOPATH=/my/actual/path/for/singularity", then the system informed me "go env -w GOPATH=... does not override conflicting OS environment variable". OK, I surrender.

So, I just "mkdir /home/{$my_username}/go" to create the directory GO forces me to :|, and "cp singularity-ce-4.0.0.tar.gz" into that directory, and "tar" it.

This time I go into the directory singularity-ce-4.0.0 and "./mconfig", it worked out.

This verifies said the upper guy :"I was struggling with the same error. All the suggestions say that probably you have an older version of Go and that's why. But turned out it's even more important to place Go and Singularity in the right locations."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).